# Crash course in conditional probability?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, soft-question, online-resources

I've taken some probability classes before, but it's been a while. I'm looking for (1) some resource -- website, paper, software, book -- etc on conditional probabilities. Something which accessible to a junior/senior level undergrad. Specifically, I'm interested in the relationships described by the following example:

The nodes $A$,$B$ are independent, and node $C$ depends on both (I understand this may be an example of what's called a *directed acyclic graph*, if that is important). Let $P(A) = 0.3$, let $P(B) = 0.01$, and the let the probability of $C$ given $A$ and $B$ are true be $P(C|A,B) = 0.5$. So find $P(C)$. I believe (please correct me) that

$$P(C) = P(C|A,B)P(A)P(B) = 0.0015$$

or something like that.

That may be wrong, but that's what I'm interested in, and how to generalize these dependencies to a larger graph. And (2) -- this something that might be too complicated for a crash course -- I'm also interested in what happens if say, $A$ and $B$ in the example above were both dependent on each other, breaking the "directed acyclicness" of the graph.

Also, comment on notation. Thank you!

---

Edit: I was way off in how I understood what I was looking for. The type of dependencies associated with the nodes I described above rely on truth tables. For example, $A$'s probability distribution:

$$ D(A) = 
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \text{True} & \text{False} \\ \hline
   0.3 & 0.7 
\end{array}, \quad 
D(B) = 
\begin{array}{c|c}
  \text{True} & \text{False} \\ \hline
   0.01 & 0.99 
\end{array} $$

And $C$'s (in percentages)

[image]

Then without observable evidence, the probability that $C$ is true is $ \approx 0.9688$. How does one arrive at that value?

Comment: *Probabilités pour les non-probabilistes* if you can read French.

Comment: You don't have enough information to determine $P(C)$. Maybe $C$ is the event "either at most one of $A,B$ occurs or, if both occur, $C$ is the event that a fair coin toss comes up $H$."  Or maybe $C$ is the event "both $A,B$ occur and a fair coin comes up $H$."

Comment: That's strange, because there's Bayesian Belief Network software packages that will list the probability of $C$ occurring in the exact model I just described.

Comment: Well, then it is wrong.

Comment: Oh, my bad, they're using truth tables. So, $C$ has a $2^3$ sized truth table with probabilities for each permutation of True/False for $A$ and $B$. Any resources for that kind of stuff?

Comment: Seems like a very specific sort of situation.  Easy to write code for it yourself...maybe somebody has written general code for this sort of thing, though I am unaware of that.

Comment: General note:  I always prefer to write my own code for things of this sort.  Mindlessly relying on third party code leads to errors of the sort you made.  Every time.  The code is making a whole host of assumptions which are easy to overlook.  If you write the code yourself you will have a strong grip on the assumptions, and you can (and should) design a suite of test cases.  Free advice.

Comment: Cool, thank you. I did want to write it myself, because I'm looking at some software that does it, but their numbers seem like magic. I edited the post, to reflect very specifically what I'm trying to figure out. Would you mind taking another look?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time right now.  But in principle, knowing the probability of $C$ conditioned on every possible combination of outcomes for $A,B$ should work.  I strongly advocate writing the code yourself.